# How to display my JSON data in a comboBox?

Tags: java, json, jcombobox

I have manged to read my JSONData and now I want to display the "name" key into a combobox.
But i get a nullpointerexception of my string Array.
Before I tried to send an JSON object straight into the defaultComboBoxModel. But it need to be and String Array so when I converted it everything became null.
Why do my array get null?

My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class Planner {

    private String startingLocation;
    private String destination;
    private static Planner planner = null;
    private int id;
    private JSONArray array;
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

    public static Planner getPlanner(){

        if (planner == null ){

            planner = new Planner();

        }

        return planner;

    }

    public void setStartingLocation(String from) {

        this.startingLocation = from;       

    }

    public void setDestination(String dest) {

        this.destination = dest;

    }

    public String getStartingLocation() {

        return startingLocation;

    }

    public String getDestination() {

        return destination;

    }


    public void setID(int id) {

        this.id = id;

    }

    public void setLocationName (JSONArray array){

        this.array = (JSONArray) array;

    }

    public String[] getLocationName(){

        System.out.println(this.array.size());

      for (int i=0; i<this.array.size(); i++){

           myList = (ArrayList) this.array.get(i);
           myList.add(i, array);

       }

       System.out.println(myList);

    return  (String[]) myList.toArray();

    }

}

public void parseJsonData() throws ParseException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(jsonData);
        JSONObject topObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONObject locationList = (JSONObject) topObject.get("LocationList");
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) locationList.get("StopLocation");
        Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = array.iterator();
        String name = null;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
            Planner.getPlanner().setLocationName(array);

        }

    }

final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(Planner.getPlanner().getLocationName());
        comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
```

Comment: Where does the NPE occur? Did you debug your code?

Comment: It doesnt even work to debug the GUI dies before it even opens it was not like that before.

Comment: final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(Planner.getPlanner().getLocationName());
        comboBox = new JComboBox(model);  It never sends the model into the combobox but jumps over it and cast exception and the applicatoin doenst even start.

Comment: As for debugging: you don't need the GUI to run to debug the application. Use an external debugger.

Btw, your code doesn't seem complete, where's the definition for `comboBox`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment on the code style or design flaws, but here are some lines that look like a bug:

```
for (int i=0; i<this.array.size(); i++){
       myList = (ArrayList) this.array.get(i);
       myList.add(i, array);
}
```

`myList` is an `ArrayList` and although I don't know what `array` which is a `JSONArray` actually contains, but if it contains either strings or `JSONObject` instances casting `array.get(i)` to `ArrayList` is likely to result in a `ClassCastException`.
If `array` contains other `JSONArray`s, it might not happen though.

The next line is quite odd ass well. Assuming `array.get(i)` actually returns a list, you assing that list to `myList` and then add the array to that list, which will result in a circular reference (`array` contains the list which contains `array` etc.).

Next, you're replacing `myList` in every iteration which might not be what you want.

Assuming `array` contains `JSONArray` istances, `JSONArray` extends `ArrayList` (hence there's no `ClassCastException`) and the inner array contains strings, you might change the method to something like this:

```
public String[] getLocationName(){

    System.out.println(this.array.size());

    List<String> resultList = new LinkedList<String>();        

    for (int i=0; i<this.array.size(); i++){
       //cast the inner array to a list of Strings (assuming it only contains Strings)
       List<String> innerList = (ArrayList) this.array.get(i);

       //add the inner list to the result list
       resultList.addAll( innerList );

    }

    System.out.println(resultList );

    return  resultList.toArray(new String[resultList.size()]);
}
```

This way you'd convert a list of lists of strings (i.e. `JSONArray` containing `JSONArray`s that contain `String`s) into a flat list of strings and return that as an array.

Comment: array is a JSONArray with JSONObjects

Comment: Please provide the exact line (mark it, don't just provide the line number!) where the NPE occurs. Additionally, if the array contains JSONObjects, then you _must not_ cast to `ArrayList`. Besides that, you'd then have to extract the location property from the current element.